# C# ASHX response a stream of PDF file and Cloudflare timeout

Tags: c#, pdf, stream, cloudflare

I have an ASHX file that generate a PDF file to stream, so the user can download it.
some of them takes time and there for when using Cloudflare as WAF the timeout reaches the limit

I would like to initiate the download somehow, give the browser (or Cloudflare) a response but continue generating the file, once it is done, to stream it back.

what I have tried to do is response.Write at the beginning but then the file won't download because trying to resend header

is there a way or solution with a plugin?

I don't want to make another page making the call, generate in the background and once it is ready to initiate a download because than I would have to change a lot of code

Comment: Show us your code. (and have you investigated your slow PDF generation issues?)